# SQL Joining two tables in wp

Tags: php, wordpress

I am sorry if this question has been aske before but I have my two tables here which I am joining. The users table works fine but the member deposit table records are not retrieved. Where am I going wrong here.

```
$tbl_name  = $wpdb->prefix."member_deposit";
 $table_name  = $wpdb->prefix."users";

$results = $wpdb->get_results("select * from  $tbl_name  INNER JOIN $table_name 
ON $table_name.ID = $tbl_name.ID   WHERE $tbl_name.approve = 
'unapprove'");

 $current_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

 foreach( $results as $user_data) {


        $startTimeStamp = strtotime($user_data->deposit_date);
        $endTimeStamp = strtotime($current_date);

        $timeDiff = abs($endTimeStamp - $startTimeStamp);

        $numberDays = $timeDiff/86400;  // 86400 seconds in one day

        // and you might want to convert to integer
        $numberDays = intval($numberDays);

       $roi = $user_data->amount * 2;  
       $amount_growth = $roi - $user_data->amount;


     $output .= "<tr>
    <td> $user_data->ID</td>
    <td> R$user_data->amount</td>
    <td> $user_data->deposit_date</td>
    <td> $numberDays</td>
    <td> $user_data->Phone</td>
    <td> R$roi</td>
    <td> <form method='post'> <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Send SMS' /> </form> </td>

  </tr>";
```

Comment: Just use a regular join (remove INNER).

Comment: It's not solving the problem